# Magento CE 2 Need to get shipping quote with multiple packages on one order

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento-2.1

Most of the products we sell only fit one item per package a few will fit more than one per package.  How can we setup Magento for multiple package shipments for one order?

On our last order the customer ordered three of the same product, each product is 18 lb the UPS quote was for one 54 lb package $58.06.  When we shipped, the shipment was three 18 lb packages with a total of $72.21.

Prefer a DIY or open source solution.

Thanks

```
Magento CE 2.1
OpenSuse 13.2
Apache 2.4.10
Varnish 4.1.3
Redis 3.2.3
nginx 1.11.2
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple packaging when you create a shipment checked on Create Shipping Label and than submit shipment. You will see following screen from there you can create more than one package for single order.

[image]